# Wait on element resize done after changing width trough renderer

Tags: resize, race-condition, sequential, offsetwidth, angular-renderer2

Is there a way to detect when an html element (native element) is done with resizing after the style: width property has been changed trough the use of the angular renderer2?

I have currently implemented a font sizing system based on the width of the parent container, but I have to use a timeout seeing the innerwidth of the parent element is not final when the font sizing is called. This parent uses css-grid properties set trough the renderer2.setStyle method.

so what i want boils down to this:

renderer.setStyle(element, cssGridStyleProperty).
(wait on renderer and browser to finish rendering).
renderer.setStyle(element, fontSizeParentBasedProperty).

Comment: I've been researching for this for a while. In my case I'm fine with setTimeout, because I set my animation duration to 300ms, so when I change this property I'm animating, set a timeout for 310ms (just a really small extra time to make sure it's completly done).

Hopefully this can help you.